# Clone Stamp affecting opposite side of model?

Tags: uv, texture-painting

Relatively new to Blender! I have a textured model, and I'm trying to clean up some messy seams. (Long-term I should have placed my UV seams in less visible locations, but at this point, I'd rather use the clone stamp to fix things than repaint my entire model)

When I use the clone stamp, I set the source with the 3D cursor, but when I go to paint, the area I'm trying to paint is not affected, but instead, the opposite side is painted in unpredictable ways:

[image]
[image]

No clue why this is happening or how to fix it, the only modifier have applied is subsurf, and I can't find any mirroring options that could be affecting the clone tool. Any help is appreciated. (Using blender 2.8)

Comment: you should check your normals, if the faces are red, flip them

Comment: Did you apply scale to the object, and do you have a mirror modifier on or do you have texture paint set to symmetry on x axis?

Answer (score 1):

User [Moonboots](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/34531/moonboots) Had the (rather simple) answer, I had some flipped normals affecting where the clone tool was cloning!